# Internal Chromium postMessage event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromium, postmessage

I have an application (Vanilla JS / Weback + Babel) that uses postMessage to communicate between host page and an iframe (different domains).

I have noticed, that on IOS 12 Chrome browser does send an event that lands in my listener on interactions like button click.

Event data looks like that:

`{
  "type":"org.chromium.contextMenuMessage",
  "requestId":"CC0C490584C989ACE524F0ED69F418DD",
  "x":245,
  "y":399.5
}`

What is it? I couldn't find any resource that could explain that behaviour.

Edit: also, the strangest thing about this event is, that it seems to be present on production environment, but not on localhost.

Comment: open an issue to crbugs https://chromiumbugs.appspot.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm seeing a very similar thing on my app. I'm receiving messages into a cross-domain iframe from Chrome on iOS v12 and Chrome v76.0.3809. The content of the message I'm receiving is different, more in the form of:

```
{
    iv: e8LCrn94cSbycO3i
    payload: daPXeVR5GBg2IffLQ/2fuTmVGzJLnM++z2nC+cjR5kGcG1VhIBHni6tIrw94Gg+KvyMUMVNY3mjfJ9jMhT4g8fcnngZkiLirqoUOqMagVY3gaEzYBCb4ZVgtRelv/paccs7hc/rMi+cDr2eCOSzzKQ6fpHU=
    target_frame_id: 419b482d9b6c4565f8dd4e2f470a518
    type: org.chromium.encryptedMessage
}
```

I'm not sure what Chrome is using this data for specifically, it's most likely for communicating with add-ons.

The salient point here is that if you're listening for messages in your iframe using something like:

```
window.addEventListener('message', callback);
```

then **you will receive all messages sent via `postMessage`** and it's up to you to filter them. Any code on the page, including the browser, has the ability to send `message` events.

Comment: I saw this as well as it was triggering event code that we didnt want triggered :). We just have an extra filter now checking for origin like so: if( /https:\/\/.+\.echosign\.com/.test(e.origin) ) { /*do stuff*/ }  ... it was probably best for security to have those kinda checks anyway and we missed that.

Answer (score 1):

It only triggers a message cross-domain.  If the parent and child are on the same domain it doesn't happen. At least that's what I've found and, sadly, I'm stuck with finding more info as well.